# jqgrid - xmlstring - how to replace/refresh a single row?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, grid

I have a jqgrid which gets loaded with a xmlstring from DOM.  (Only need to support IE).

In the application when the user performs some operation, one row data gets changed and an xml response or string is made available.  This grid row needs to be updated with this new xmlstring/response.

I do not want to reload the entire grid for performance reasons.  I can not easily pre process the returned xml because that will involve complex parsing.  Ideally, I would like to use the grid's column model and custom formatters of the jqgrid.

I tried using  addXMLData() but that replaces the entire grid.   addXMLData() requires a data object, which means I will have pre-process the xml response.

What is the a good approach to handling this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try setRowData method

jQuery("#your_grid_id").jqGrid('setRowData',rowid,modifiedRowdata);

[Read more](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)